# How can I perform an arbitrary aggregate method on an arbitrary column in a DataTable in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, aggregate

That question is terrible; I know. If I could word it better, I might be able to find a solution. Here's the detail:

Assume I have a DataTable with three columns, named "one", "two", and "three", all of type int. If I want the sum of the third column, that's easy enough:

```
var sum = DataTable.AsEnumerable().ToList().Sum(row => row["three"] as int?).Value;
```

Since I'm working on infrastructure-level stuff and subsets of rows, it's better to think of it as a method on a separate class.

```
var sum = GetSummary();
...
public class calculator {
    List<DataRow> data;
    public int GetSummary() { return this.data.Sum(row => row["three"] as int?).Value; }
}
```

The hard part is that I need to allow the caller to specify the aggregate method and the column on which to perform it.

```
var desire = <get the average of the column called "two">
var result = GetAggregation(DataTable.AsEnumerable().ToList(), desire);
...
public class calculator {
    List<DataRow> data;
    public int GetAggregation(List<DataRow> data, <something> actionToPerform) { ... }
}
```

What is my `desire`? Is it a Func()? Something else entirely? What would it look like in the examples here?

The best I've been able to come up with is this:

```
public class calculator {
    List<DataRow> data;
    public T? DoAggregation<T> (string column, Func<IEnumerable<T?>, T> desire) {
        var subset = data.Select(row => row.Field<T>(column)).ToArray();
        return desire(subset);
    }
}

public class tester {
    public class DoTest() {
        var mycalc = new calculator();
        var avgResult = mycalc.DoAggregation<double>("two", desire: (data) => data.Average());
        var sumResult = mycalc.DoAggregation<int>("three", desire: (data) => data.Sum());
    }
}
```

It's a step forward, but it has its own issues. Since I need to store these `desires`, my calculator needs a collection of type `List<Func<IEnumerable<T>, T>>` ... but then I can't have `desires` of different types (int vs decimal). And how would I handle something like `<add column one to column three on each row and take the average across all rows>`?

Comment: I think the answer depends on who is creating the methods: is it the end user or the application programmer? If the end user, you will probably end up with a simplified expression language that you parse to create methods. If the programmer, how do you expect the programmer to handle the differing return types? In any case, your final example expression implies passing a single column name is a mistake, so you should have `Func<IEnumerable<DataRow>, T>` instead and have the method access the columns needed.

Comment: While not exactly directly applicable, it might also be worth noting that `DataTable`s support calculated columns using the [`DataColumn.Expression` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-7.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not as generic as possible, I've found a solution that works for me. This component is being used to render reports, so anything and everything that it would be used for would result in a string. My last paragraph of the question was concerned about returning different types, but that's not really an issue.

With that said, I've ended up with:

```
public void AddDetailComponent(Func<DataRow, string> toPerform) {}
```

Per @NetMage's comment, this component will be used by other programmers. I have to trust that they're capable of writing functions that return strings. If I can't trust that, I need to look at who's being hired.

So typical usage would look like this:

```
report.AddDetailComponent((data) =>
{
    var value = (bool)data[DataTableColumns.FirstColumnName] ? (int?)data[DataTableColumns.SecondColumnName] * 2 : (int?)data[DataTableColumns.SecondColumnName] / 2;
            return value.ToString();
});
```